# Having trouble defining grid areas with ngStyle

Tags: css, angular, typescript, css-grid, ng-style

I created a mechanism for generating CSS Grids which I'm trying to implement with `ngStyle`.  Here's what's generated

```
"GridAreas": {
    "LinkContainer": "{'grid-area': 'link-row-start / content-col-start / link-row-end / content-col-end'}",
    "BodySection"  : "{'grid-area': 'content-row-start / content-col-start / content-row-end / content-col-end', 'justify-content': 'stretched'}",
    "FooterSection": "{'grid-area': 'footer-row-start / content-col-start / footer-row-end / footer-col-end'}"
}
```

I tried using it in the html like this

```
<link-container [ngStyle]="Output.GridAreas.LinkContainer" [SiteLinks]="Links"></link-container>
```

and I got this error

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '{'grid-area': 'link-row-start / content-col-start / link-row-end / content-col-end'}'

I then tried using functions like this

```
loadLinkArea(){  return this.Output.GridAreas.LinkContainer;  }
```

calling in the HTML like this

```
<link-container [ngStyle]="loadLinkArea()"></link-container>
```

I received the same exact error.  Here's how the data gets processed.

**Shape of overall data**

```
export class GridType {
    GridName : string          = '';
    Columns  : Array<GridLine> = new Array();
    Rows     : Array<GridLine> = new Array();
    Areas    : Array<AreaList> = new Array(); /*the part I'm focusing on*/
    Type     : string          = '';
}

export class AreaList {
    AreaName : string = '';
    Specs    : GridArea = new GridArea();
}

export class GridArea {
    Area    : string = '';
    Params? : Array<ParamData> = new Array();
}

export class ParamData {
    Param   : string = '';
    Setting : string = '';
}
```

**Areas Data**

```
Areas    : [
        {
            AreaName : 'LinkContainer',
            Specs    : { Area: 'link-row-start / content-col-start / link-row-end / content-col-end' }
        },
        {
            AreaName : 'BodySection',
            Specs    : {
                Area    : 'content-row-start / content-col-start / content-row-end / content-col-end',
                Params  : [    { Param: 'justify-content', Setting: 'stretched' }    ]
            }
        },
        {
            AreaName : 'FooterSection',
            Specs    : { Area: 'footer-row-start / content-col-start / footer-row-end / footer-col-end' }
        }
    ]
```

The above body of data gets passed into this function

```
export function buildGridAreas( data: AreaList[] ){
    let areas: StringList = new StringList();

    data.forEach( a => {
        let b: string = '';
        if( a.Specs.Params ){
            let c: string[] = [];

            a.Specs.Params.forEach(  prs => {
                const d: string = "'"+prs.Param+"': "+prs.Setting;
                c.push(d);
            });
            b = "{'grid-area': "+a.Specs.Area+", "+c.join(', ')+"}";
        }
        else{ b = "{'grid-area': "+a.Specs.Area+"}"; }
        areas[ a.AreaName ]=b;
    });
    return areas;
}
```

the rest of the code that generates for defining the grid looks like this

```
 "GridCode": "[top-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [top-bleed-end link-row-start] 40.9800000000041px [link-row-end content-row-start] [content-row-end footer-row-start] 163.9200000000164px [footer-row-end bottom-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [bottom-bleed-end]/[left-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [left-bleed-end content-col-start] 1331.8500000001332px [content-col-end right-bleed-start] 10.245000000001024px [right-bleed-end]"
```

Can anybody spot where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for `ngStyle` is like this:

```
<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color' : color}"></div>
```

If you do that, the attribute value is an *expression*. So in your case, Angular treats the value of `Output.GridAreas.LinkContainer` as an expression. On the other hand, it seems you expected the value of `Output.GridAreas.LinkContainer` to be treated as if it has been literally the attribute value in the first place.

As far as I understand your code, the solution should be simple: just remove the doublequotes from the right-hand side of your style declarations, i.e. just use plain objects.

[UPDATE] In response to your comment, just two snippets of code:

a) This component basically does what you had in your initial problem description:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<div [ngStyle]="Output.GridAreas.LinkContainer">Works</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public Output = {
        GridAreas: {
            LinkContainer: "{'grid-area': 'link-row-start / content-col-start / link-row-end / content-col-end'}"
        }
    };
}
```

This code will result in the “Cannot find a differ …” error you mentioned.

b) Code with the quotes removed, which will work:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `<div [ngStyle]="Output.GridAreas.LinkContainer">Works</div>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    public Output = {
        GridAreas: {
            LinkContainer: {'grid-area': 'link-row-start / content-col-start / link-row-end / content-col-end'}
        }
    };
}
```

I admit I was not committed enough to go through all your code in detail (BTW: IMO, the code would become more readable if it was using ES6 template strings), but it looks like you construct strings instead of objects. In other words, instead of …

```
b = "{'grid-area': "+a.Specs.Area+"}";
```

… you should use something like …

```
b = {'grid-area': a.Specs.Area};
```

(untested). So it seems to be a problem of how you construct your code, not an Angular problem.

Comment: I modified my functions to take off the quotes and got the same result.  I just updated my post to show how things are being put together, hopefully that will help shed light on the issue.